# Cannot find Address 1: Shipping Method field for Accounts Entity in MS Flow

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, power-automate, dynamics-365-sales

I am creating a Microsoft Flow for creating new records for 'Accounts' entity. However, I cannot find the 'Address 1: Shipping Method' attribute for Accounts in the list of attributes appearing when Accounts entity is selected.

All other attributes are appearing but not this one. Please refer to screenshot:
https://www.screencast.com/t/KhiIdyRXlEQ5

Is there some setting which I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sound like a bug in Microsoft side.

I quickly checked in my vanilla instance, able to find the regular `Shipping Method` picklist in MS Flow action.

[image]

Whereas `Address 1: Shipping Method` and `Address 2: Shipping Method` optionsets are missing.

I would recommend you to open a ticket with Microsoft support or feedback in any documentation link to get immediate attention.

Comment: Already done. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/I-Found-A-Bug/Cannot-find-Address-1-Shipping-Method-field-for-Accounts-Entity/m-p/310671#M4688